# Adobe Photoshop method to give results equivalent to 'Background Blur' in Adobe XD

Tags: adobe-photoshop, blur, adobe-xd

I am searching for a way to make a blurred object in Adobe Photoshop like the image I've made in Adobe XD with the Background-Blur tool.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one simple method. There may be others . . .

1. Create a copy of the background layer, and apply some Gaussian blur to it.
2. Use the elliptical selection tool to make a circle, then add it as a layer mask
3. Add a layer above, fill it with white, reduce the layer opacity to something like 50%, then clip it to the blurred layer below
4. To move the circle around, select the Move Tool and switch off *Auto-Select* in the tool options along the top, select the layer mask, and unlink the mask from the image

Example:

[image]

Comment: Alternatively, make the background layer a Smart Object before duplicating it, so any changes will reflect on both automagically.

Comment: @Luciano Absolutely!  This would also be especially helpful if the background image itself was in fact a layered image that might need edited in the future.